# Spring Batch default beans not included

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-batch

I only use annotation driven configuration, no XML hell, including a spring batch application into my spring mvc rest based application.

The spring-batch configuration file starts like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
[...]
```

IntelliJ puts a mark on those beans, telling me it could not autowire as no beans of 'JobBuilderFactory' / 'StepBuilderFactory' type were found. AFAIK the annotation `@EnableBatchProcessing` should make those beans available.

The application does compile, so spring-batch seems to be included. In my pom.xml I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I can autowire other beans (`private Environment environment`) in the same file, so autowiring itself works. Which steps do i need to find the solution? Could it only be an Intellij issue as it compiles?

Comment: Have you actually run the application? The fact that your IDE tells you that something is wrong doesn't mean there is something wrong. Depending on your Intellij version you might not have support for Spring Batch enabled or Spring Batch support with annotations isn't supported yet.

Comment: The application itself runs. I use the latest Intellij version (14.0.2 - should have mentioned this). I am rather looking to fix the misconfiguration as it is simply annoying. Spring Batch support for Intellij and this project is enabled.

Comment: Not sure if IntelliJ already supports the Spring Batch annotation driven approach next to that make sure you have added this class to the Spring Configuration of your project.

Comment: That could be the issue. I thought this autowiring would not be dependent on Spring Batch itself but I may be wrong.

Comment: Well it is and the `@EnableBatchProcessing` imports other configuration which exposes beans and I'm not certain if Intellij picks that up already.

Comment: From what I'm aware (I'm still on 13), IntelliJ hasn't picked up the new java configuration for Spring Batch yet.  I was hoping it would be picked up in 14, but it doesn't look like it yet.  That being said, the issue is an IDE one, not a code one.

Comment: Okay, this sounds reasonable. I just searched in the IntelliJ resources and there is an open feature request (you may need to log in): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127346

Answer (score 4):

EnableBatchProcessing annotation need to be added along with @Configration

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue as well. In my configuration class, I got the same autowire problems and non of the suggested solutions worked for me. Finally, I managed to overcome this tedious issue as follows:

[image: Resolution]

Basically, you just need to enable Spring Batch plugin in settings.

Comment: Just in case, this plugin also available on Marketplace https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18505-spring-batch

Answer (score 1):

At the moment IntelliJ Idea does not support default batch context resolution:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127346

To suppress warnings you may annotate such fields like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Autowired
JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
```